# How to "find files that has both A and B in the code" using Note++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I find that "Find in files" of Note++ is a great thing to understand a somewhat complicated program.

But then I am trying to find py files (in some certain directory) that contain both A and B in the code.

I guess I have to use regex, but couldn't do it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but I'd imagine something like this would work (while consuming lots of memory):

```
.*(word1.*word2|word2.*word1).*
```

You'll need to make sure that you check the `. matches newline` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The general regex for this is:

```
^(?s)(?=.*A).*B.*
```

(Replacing A and B for whatever expressions or literals you are looking for.)

This matches the entire content of the file.

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
(?s)                     # set flags for this block (with . matching
                         # \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                         # matching normally) (matching whitespace
                         # and # normally)
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  .*                     #   any character (0 or more times (matching
                         #   the most amount possible))
  A                      #   'A'
)                        # end of look-ahead
.*                       # any character (0 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
B                        # 'B'
.*                       # any character (0 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
```